# How to set a bower package dependencies?

Tags: angularjs, package, bower

I'm creating a bower package named X who depends to `angular-local-storage`.
I saved `angular-local-storage` in my `bower.json`.

My module is declared as : 
`angular.module('X', ['LocalStorageModule']);`

The service as :

```
angular
  .module('X')
  .service('XService', XService);

function XService($resource, $q, $window, LocalStorageService) {...}
```

When I install the package X with bower in another project, `LocalStorageModule` is not found.

How can I manage this dependencies ?

EDIT : the error is:

`Unknown provider: LocalStorageServiceProvider <- LocalStorageService <- XService`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to build a bower package, you need to make sure you follow these steps:

## bower package: X

1. prepare a bower.json with this following (minimal) configuration:

   ```
   {
     "name": "your-package-x",
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "main": "dist/your-package-x.min.js",
     "dependencies": {
       "angular": "1.5.0",
       "angular-local-storage": "2.0.7"
       ...
     }
   }
   ```
2. build all the package's files into **dist/your-package-x.min.js** (using your favorite build tool)
3. if the package has HTML templates, you should build a templateCache file and append it to the built file (using your build tool):

   a. exemple with grunt: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-angular-templates

   b. exemple with gulp: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-templatecache
4. publish to bower

## External project

1. add **your-package-x** dependency to your bower.json:

   ```
   {
     "name": "main-project",
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "dependencies": {
       "your-package-x": "path to repo or version"
       ...
     }
   }
   ```
2. install bower deps
3. Inject the package-x and its dependencies:

   ```
   <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="bower_components/angular-local-storage/dist/angular-local-storage.min.js"></script>
   <script src="bower_components/dist/your-package-x/dist/your-package-x.min.js"></script>
   ```

   ==> or use a build tool to do it for you (look for **wiredep**)

I hope this quick guide would help.

Answer (score 2):

- Add 'LocalStorageModule' to your main module's list of dependencies.
- Include **angular-local-storage.js** (or angular-local-storage.min.js) from the dist directory in your index.html, after including Angular itself.

**More**

I would suggest you layout your factory or service this way:

```
.service('ServiceName', ['$log','OtherService', function($log, OtherService){
   var serviceInstance = {};
   //stuff
   return serviceInstance;
}]);
```

This has more boilerplate than you absolutely need, but it is minification safe and keeps your namespaces clean.

Comment: `LocalStorageModule` is in the main list and I still have the error when I add the directive to a view. (the lib is also include in index.html) And I just notice that directive include the index.html so angular is dependencies is set two times : `WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.`

Comment: when you installed this module did bower asked you to update some dependencies with ! (persistance) ? show me the bower.json and the index.html